# IP mask in JavaScript (Titanium)

Tags: javascript, titanium

Hi i am creating a client APP for IPAD, i need to make the textfield of the IP address like the Windows TCP/IP settings(  .  .  .  ) the user can only write numbers in the four spaces. Each segment must be between 0 and 255, how can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for might be some JavaScript library to mask the  control like [this](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-input-ip-address-control/)

Comment: Thanks, how can i insert this in a titanium project?

Answer (score 0):

Most of JavaScript libraries are designed for use in browser, so you can not use them in native code but you can use it in web view .

I have used [Redux](https://github.com/dawsontoth/Appcelerator-Titanium-Redux) library(read README.md first).

Also you can find more libraries [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Third-party+Tools#Third-partyTools-UtilityLibraries).

Hope it helps you.